# OpenCV: A straighforward method of colorizing a grayscale image

Tags: c++, opencv

What is a straight forward method of "colorizing" a grayscale image. By colorizing, I mean porting the grayscale intensity values to one of the three R, G, B channels in a new image.

For example a `8UC1` grayscale pixel with intensity of `I = 50` should become a `8UC3` color pixel of intensity `BGR = (50, 0, 0)` when the picture is colorized to "blue".

In Matlab for example, what I'm asking for can be simply created with two lines of code:

```
color_im = zeros([size(gray_im) 3], class(gray_im));
color_im(:, :, 3) = gray_im;
```

But amazingly I cannot find anything similar in OpenCV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the same thing requires a bit more work in C++ and OpenCV:

```
// Load a single-channel grayscale image
cv::Mat gray = cv::imread("filename.ext", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

// Create an empty matrix of the same size (for the two empty channels)
cv::Mat empty = cv::Mat::zeros(gray.size(), CV_8UC1);

// Create a vector containing the channels of the new colored image
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;

channels.push_back(gray);   // 1st channel
channels.push_back(empty);  // 2nd channel
channels.push_back(empty);  // 3rd channel

// Construct a new 3-channel image of the same size and depth
cv::Mat color;
cv::merge(channels, color);
```

or as a function (compacted):

```
cv::Mat colorize(cv::Mat gray, unsigned int channel = 0)
{
    CV_Assert(gray.channels() == 1 && channel <= 2);

    cv::Mat empty = cv::Mat::zeros(gray.size(), gray.depth());
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3, empty);
    channels.at(channel) = gray;

    cv::Mat color;
    cv::merge(channels, color);
    return color;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that right after I asked this question, I found out about the `cv::merge()` function and the `vector` of `cv::Mat` and did exactly the same thing you did here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are [special function to do this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) - *applyColorMap* in OpenCV from v2.4.5 in *contrib* module. There are different color maps available:

[image: Color maps]

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to help achieve the desired output? Obviously, one cannot define custom color maps.